Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization and Legendre equation
Can anyone help to explain why the  polynomials obtained by  orthogonalizing the sequence $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, ...\}$ following the Gram-Schmidt process happen to satisfy Legendre’s differential equation?
The inner product is defined as
\begin{equation}
\langle f(x), g(x) \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) g(x) \, dx \,.
\end{equation}

What is your inner product?

@Nothingspecial Good question, answered here.

@J.G. Hi, the wikipage you provided is excellent and very fun to read, but it still didn't answer my question...

Have you tried anything? I would suggest induction by $n$. Take the general formula for the orthogonalisation of monomials: $P_{k+1}(x)= x^{k+1} - \sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(x^k, P_i)}{||{P_i}||^2} P_i(x)$, take its two derivatives and insert it into the differential equation. Upon using the premise of induction, I believe, it should lead to answer (I haven't tried it, though).

There's a typo in the formula above. It should be $x^{k+1}$, of course, in the dot product.

Unfortunately you're right, it didn't. I was telling @Nothingspecial it answers their question.
